# Scala: Method receive as parameter a List[T] and with pattern matching it proves if the received list is not a List[B]

Tags: list, scala, types, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a the following class: 
`case class Car(name: String)`

then I make a List with instances of Car

`val bmw = Car("BMW")`
`val audi = Car("Audi")`

`val cars: List[Car] = List(bmw, audi)`

I want to have a method which with pattern matching proves if the received list is not a list of type Car / List[Car]

```
def matchNotCarList[T](list: List[T]) = list match {
    case (don´t know) => "It is not a list with Car elements" 
    case Nil => "empty list"
    case _ => "is a list with car elements"
}
```

How should the first case be??

Notice: I don´t want the case to prove if it is a List[Car], I want it to prove if it is not.

I don´t know if insted of having a List[T] as type parameter I should use List[Any]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the head and check its type:

```
case h :: _ if !h.isInstanceOf[Car] => "It is not a list with Car elements"
```